# Spring Security: force request of new OAuth2 access token before it is expired

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

Spring Security keeps a refresh token internally, and only requests a new access token when the "current" access token is expired.

However, how to explicitly request/force Spring Security to request a new access token from the Authorization Server, even though the current access token is not expired yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you.

```
curl -v --data "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=THE_CLIENT_ID&refresh_token=THE_REFRESH_TOKEN" http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
```